# Why is select() returning 1 but recv() returning 0?

Tags: c++, windows, select, networking, winsock2

I can see clearly that `recvbuf` has all the data I was expecting yet `select()` keeps returning 1.

Right now it's stuck in the limbo of `else if (iBuffer == 0) {}`.

```
SOCKET m_ConnectSocket;
/* The socket setup is done elsewhere but just adding this for clarity
   This socket is responsible for sending from the client to the server
   and also receives anything the server sends back.

   This socket is doing the connect() & initial send()
*/

fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;

// Set up the file descriptor set.
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(m_ConnectSocket, &set);

// Set up the struct timeval for the timeout.
timeout.tv_sec  = RECV_DELAY_SEC;
timeout.tv_usec = RECV_DELAY_USEC;

int iBuffer = 0;

do
{
    iResult = select(m_ConnectSocket, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (iResult > 0)
    {
        iBuffer = recv(m_ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
        if (iBuffer > 0)
        {
            string sRecv(recvbuf);

            STrace = String::Format("Bytes Received: {0}", iBuffer);
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);

            STrace = String::Format("Data Received: [{0}]", gcnew String(sRecv.c_str()));
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);
        }
        else if (iBuffer == 0)
        {
            STrace = String::Format("iBuffer empty");
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);
        }
        else
        {
            STrace = String::Format("recv failed: {0}", WSAGetLastError());
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_ERROR);
        }
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
    {
        STrace = String::Format("No data left in buffer");
        Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);

        pMessage->Data(recvbuf);
        if (iSentType != pMessage->Type())
        {
            STrace = String::Format("Message type mismatch: {0} | Expected: {1}", (int)pMessage->Type(), (int)iSentType);
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_WARNING);
        }
    }
    else if (iResult == -1)
    {
        STrace = String::Format("select() error");
        Trace(STrace, TRACE_ERROR);
    }
} while (iResult > 0);
```

Comment: Does select return 1 the first or subsequent time around the loop?

Comment: Is this a UDP connection? What is the value of DEFAULT_BUFLEN? Why are you passing `m_connectSocket` to select instead of `1`? (first parameter of select is supposed to be the number of file descriptors to check).

Comment: AFAIR, the first argument to `select()` is he number of slots in the sets to be chacked for, not the number of the greatest descriptor in them. Therefore, iff `m_ConnectSocket` is the highest fd in the sets, I think you should do `select(m_ConnectSocket+1, ...)`.

Comment: Subsequent times. I let it loop probably about 50 times. It's a TCP stream.

Comment: I thought you need to reset `set` and `timeout` before the call each time. Maybe wrong

Comment: Do you have any reference for changing the first param of `select()`. IIRC docs had me passing it the socket to check.

Comment: The name `m_connectSocket` makes it sound like this is the `listen` socket... You don't receive data on the listen socket, instead you have to `accept` from it which produces an actual stream socket for you to read/write with.

Comment: @Ed Heal Maybe.. could be on to something there. Probably not `timeout` but maybe `set`.

Comment: @Enigma `man 2 select`, or e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/2/select

Comment: @Enigma I'm wrong about that - according to msdn that parameter is ignored. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) but in berkeley sockets, it should be highest-socket + 1 (http://linux.die.net/man/2/select)

Comment: @EdHeal you're absolutely correct; select changes the fdsets, that's why it takes them as pointers, so you can tell which sockets lit up, so to speak.

Comment: On some platforms, the `timeout` is updated to reflect the time remaining. On other platforms, `timeout` is not updated.  Best to reset it each time, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `select` has it parameters passed as pointer and those data structures get altered by `select` put

```
fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;

// Set up the file descriptor set.
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(m_ConnectSocket, &set);

// Set up the struct timeval for the timeout.
timeout.tv_sec  = RECV_DELAY_SEC;
timeout.tv_usec = RECV_DELAY_USEC;
```

Just before the  `select` statement i.e. within the loop.

Comment: So I did this but I still enter into a forever 1 situation occasionally. I'm wondering now though if it has something to do with the state of the socket on the opposing side.

Comment: It occurs fairly uncommonly and (i think) only when I have breakpoints being hit in the flow.

Comment: When it returns 1, recv could be returning -1. Therefore that socket has closed.

Comment: @EdHeal: If the connection is closed *gracefully*, `select()` will report readability, and `recv()` will return 0, not -1.

Answer (score 7):

All the answers so far are correct in what they say about resetting the FD sets, but none of them has actually identified the underlying problem.

If `recv()` returns zero it means the peer has disconnected, and you must close the socket. If you don't, as you aren't, you will continue to select the socket as readable and continue to receive zero.

It does *not* mean 'buffer empty'.

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing `select()`.  Please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx):

> Parameters
>
> nfds [in]
>   **Ignored**. The nfds parameter is included only for compatibility with Berkeley sockets.
>
> ...
>
> **Upon return, the structures are updated** to reflect the subset of these sockets that meet the specified condition.

So you *must* reset the `fd_set` structure every time you call `select()` in your loop.

Also, it looks like when `select()` times out, you are trying to parse whatever was received, but you are only parsing the last buffer that was returned by the last successful `recv()`, if any.  In case `recv()` has to be called multiple times before the data times out, you need to collect each returned buffer and then parse them all together as a whole.

Also, your error handling in general could use some improvement, too.

Try something more like this instead:

```
fd_set set;
struct timeval timeout;

string sBuffer;
int iBuffer;

do
{
    // Set up the file descriptor set.
    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(m_ConnectSocket, &set);

    // Set up the struct timeval for the timeout.
    timeout.tv_sec  = RECV_DELAY_SEC;
    timeout.tv_usec = RECV_DELAY_USEC;

    iResult = select(0, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
    if (iResult > 0)
    {
        iBuffer = recv(m_ConnectSocket, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
        if (iBuffer > 0)
        {
            string sRecv(recvbuf, iBuffer);

            STrace = String::Format("Bytes Received: {0}", iBuffer);
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);

            STrace = String::Format("Data Received: [{0}]", gcnew String(sRecv.c_str()));
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);

            sBuffer += sRecv;
        }
        else
        {
            if (iBuffer == 0)
            {
                STrace = String::Format("Connection closed");
                Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);
            }
            else
            {
                STrace = String::Format("recv failed: {0}", WSAGetLastError());
                Trace(STrace, TRACE_ERROR);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
    {
        STrace = String::Format("No data left in buffer");
        Trace(STrace, TRACE_INFO);

        pMessage->Data(sBuffer.c_str());
        if (iSentType != pMessage->Type())
        {
            STrace = String::Format("Message type mismatch: {0} | Expected: {1}", (int)pMessage->Type(), (int)iSentType);
            Trace(STrace, TRACE_WARNING);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        STrace = String::Format("select failed: {0}", WSAGetLastError());
        Trace(STrace, TRACE_ERROR);
    }
}
while (iResult > 0);
```

Comment: Doesn't identify the actual problem, and doesn't correctly handle the data, or end of stream, and doesn't handle errors on `recv()` at all. `select()` returning zero does not mean 'no data left in buffer', and assuming that a read timeout equals end of message is invalid.

Comment: @user207421 "*Doesn't identify the actual problem*" - one problem amongst several. "*doesn't correctly handle the data*" - in what way? "*or end of stream*" - the loop is broken on EOS w/logging. "*doesn't handle errors on `recv()` at all*" - the loop is broken on error w/logging. "*`select()` returning zero does not mean 'no data left in buffer'*" - the code assumes end-of-msg on timeout, as the data is not being framed. Some protocols work that way, but framing is best in most cases. "*assuming that a read timeout equals end of message is invalid.*" - depends on protocol and timeout length